# Problems after updating SVN to 1.8.3 on Ubuntu 12.10 (using WANdisco package)

Tags: ubuntu, svn

```
apache2: Syntax error on line 203 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf:
Syntax error on line 2 of /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/authz_svn.load:
Cannot load /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_authz_svn.so into server:
/usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_authz_svn.so: undefined symbol: dav_svn_get_repos_path
Action 'configtest' failed.
```

I get this error after updating SVN on Ubunutu (12.10 Quantal) when I try to restart the server. All the modules dav, dav_svn and authz_svn are in place an running. Unfortunately., searching for the error in a search engine of my choice doesn't get me any further.
When accessing svn via a browser it still tells the version to be 1.7.5.x when do a 'svn help' it shows 1.8.3.x

After downgrading to 1.7.5 again, I get this:

```
Syntax error on line 203 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf:
Syntax error on line 2 of /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/authz_svn.load: Cannot load
/usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_authz_svn.so into server: libsvn_repos-1.so.0:
cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got similar errors after installing custom Subversion 1.7 Apache modules in Ubuntu 12.04.  The modules must be loaded in this order: dav -> dav_svn_module -> authz_svn_module, for the libraries to load properly.  The libapache2-svn Ubuntu package seems to handle this with 'Depends:' comments at the top of the .load files:

/etc/apache2/mods-available/dav_svn.load:

```
# Depends: dav
LoadModule dav_svn_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_dav_svn.so
```

/etc/apache2/mods-available/authz_svn.load

```
# Depends: dav_svn
LoadModule authz_svn_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_authz_svn.so
```

In my experience, my custom modules are enabled/disabled based on those dependencies, but Apache still tries to load /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/* in alphabetical order, therefore loading authz_svn.load first and getting the above error.  I don't know how the libapache2-svn package avoids this problem while custom modules do not.

I've worked around the problem by removing the mods-available/mods-enabled dav_svn.load and authz_svn.load files entirely.  Then I put this into /etc/apache2/httpd.conf:

```
LoadModule dav_svn_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_dav_svn.so
LoadModule authz_svn_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_authz_svn.so
```

Order matters, obviously.  Apache loads httpd.conf after mods-enabled, so now Apache starts for me.